# Compare glmer to glm after mice imputation

Tags: statistics, imputation

I would like to test the significance of my random effects term after multiple imputation with mice. I have two nested models which I try to compare with pool compare, however this creates some error.

fm1 <- with(dti.mice1, glmer(Treatment ~ (1|Hospital) + Age))

fm2 <- with (dti.mice1, glm(Treatment ~ Age))

pool.compare (fm1, fm2)

Error: Model 'fit1' not larger than 'fit0'

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be, that fm1 and fm2 are not recognized as nested models
(with fm1 being the larger model).

From the **mice** documentation:

> **fit1**
>   An object of class 'mira', produced by with.mids().
>
> **fit0**
>   An object of class 'mira', produced by with.mids(). The model in fit0 is a nested fit0 of fit1.

So the complete/ larger model has to be fit1. Which is the case for your example.
Might be that you can't use glm and glmer together. What happens, if you use glm for both models? Does this work?